# How do I divide a set of numbers in two subsets with equal number of elements and sum closest as possible?

Tags: algorithm, math

Given a set of n numbers, with n even, how do I get two subsets of n/2 numbers each and where the sum of the numbers in each subset is as close as possible?

Example: 
Set={1.6, 4.0, 0.7, 2.9, 5.0, 3.1, 5.0, 1.0, 0.6, 5.0} with sum 28.9

Subsets could be:
{5.0, 5.0, 2.9, 1.0, 0.6} with sum 14.5 and 
{5.0, 4.0, 3.1, 1.6, 0.7} with sum 14.4

I need an algorithm, pseudocode is fine.

Thanks!

Comment: This is [a well-known problem in computer science](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: @RaymondChen I know, there are lot of solutions for subsets with different number of elements. I need each subset with the same number of elements. There is no solution for my case in that Wikipedia link, but thanks anyway.

Comment: If M is the largest element in your set, then you can add (M+1)n to each value and then solve it as a regular partition sum problem. The minimal partition of this problem gives you the minimal partition of size n/2.

Comment: @PaulHankin Would you please write some pseudocode with that solution? Because I still don't get it. Then we han put it in an answer and I choose it as the right one? Thanks!

Comment: @PaulHankin is it going to work when negative numbers are allowed?

Comment: @algrid You can convert a problem with negative values to one where all values are positive.

Answer (score 0):

The way I looked at it was: there are two lists, empty. a=[ ], b=[ ]
For each element in x (a list of numbers), append it to the one that needs it the most, that is, whose sum is less than the other.

```
x=[1.6, 4.0, 0.7, 2.9, 5.0, 3.1, 5.0, 1.0, 0.6, 5.0]
x.sort()
x.reverse()
print(x)
#[5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.1, 2.9, 1.6, 1.0, 0.7, 0.6]
b=[];c=[]
for i in a:
    if sum(b) <= sum(c):
        b.append(i)
    else:
        c.append(i)
print(sum(b))
print(sum(c))

#Hope this helps!
```

Edits:
If we want the sets to be equally sized, then that can become a problem. Using combinatorics will take a long time, but I see no other option. Then again, I have limited knowledge. So here goes:
Given a set of 22, find a set of 11 that sums to half that of 22, or comes as close as possible. If it comes as close as possible, see if switching elements will produce better results. But that's as inefficient as combinatorics.

This is a really hard problem. Even wikipedia admits it. :-D :-(

Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: It wont always finish with two subsets with same number of elements

Comment: @Ramiro Yeah, but getting the sum closer seemed more important. You could have [5,1,1,1,1,1] become [5] & [1,1,1,1,1] which is better than [5,1,1] and [1,1,1].

Comment: And then alternating wouldn't work to get the precisely half method. I'm thinking that the list gets summed and divided, and the program tries to get subsets that get as close to that half-sum as possible.

Comment: I understand but I need two subsets with equal number of elements. And sum of each subset closest as possible. But same number of elements in each subset